# How do I equate coefficients with complex numbers in polynomial equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

I need assistance with this question:

$z = 2 - 5i$ is one of the roots to $z^{3} - (2-5i)z^{2} + 16z - 32 +80i = 0$.
Find all the roots.

So, I have expanded it out using the pair of conjugate complex numbers but my a and b variables when equating coefficients seems to be incorrect.

if $z = 2 - 5i$  is one of the solutions, then so must be $z = 2 + 5i$

This is what my expansion looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRDNo.jpg

ie:
$az^{3} + (b-4a)z^{2} + (29a - 4b)z + 29b$

so, my attempt at equating coefficients are as follows

$z^{3}$:

$a = 1$

$x^{2}$:

$b - 4a = 5i -2$

$ b =5i - 2 + 4 $

$b = 5i +2$

$x^{1}$:

$29a - 4b = 16$

$b = 13/4$

so, the variable b does not match with values from the $x^{2}$ and $x^{1}$ coefficients.

when checking with the $z^{0}$ coefficient, none of the values match $-31 + 80i$.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: ok - i will make the edit

Comment: ok, completed the edit everyone!

Comment: As José Carlos Santos's answer implies, you can only assume roots come in conjugate pairs when the coefficients are real.

Comment: ohhh. so the i means the coefficients aren't real? I have mostly only come across questions with real coefficients.

Comment: Yes, $i$ isn't real, so any coefficient it appears in isn't real either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: The conjugate root theorem only works when the coefficients of the equation are *real*.

So you only have one root to work with here - however this question is still very possible if you consider the sums and products of roots, or if you instead factor the equation like so:

$$(z-(2-5i))(az^2+bz+c)$$

You will then need to expand this and equate coefficients to find values for $a$, $b$ and $c$, and then factor the quadratic to find the other two roots.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey  - i got 195i - 106 for the z^0 coefficient, after subbing in "c". is that correct?

Comment: @Chris You will find it much easier to instead consider the sum and product of roots. For example, let the roots be a and b, and then we know that the product of roots = ab(2-5i)=32-80i so then we have ab=16. Then find a similar equation for the sum of roots and then solve for a and b.

Comment: where would i start to find a similar equation for the sum of roots? I am a bit stumped because this polynomial is a cubic, not a quadratic?

Comment: @Chris No worries - For any polynomial, the sum of its roots is just -n/k, where n is the first term, and k is the second term. So in your case the sum of roots would be: 2-5i =  (2-5i)+a+b so then we get a=-b which you can combine with ab=16 to get your answer. If you need any more clarification, ask more questions - I don't mind at all answering.

Comment: where does the sum of roots come from? it is based off the quadratic one? ie. -b/a ?

Comment: But by subbing a = -b, -b (b) = 16 so -b^2 =16 ? 

wouldn't the negative sign prevent a square root on both sides?

Comment: can you clarify where the right side of equation comes from?  2-5i = (2-5i)+a+b

oh wait, that a & b is the sum of the roots?
LHS is sum of the roots: -b/a = (2-5i)/1. RHS is sum of the roots: let root 1 be a and the other be b: (2-5i)+a+b
LHS = RHS

Comment: sorry if im asking too much haha

Comment: yep you got it right: -b^2=16 involves imaginary numbers, however you said you haven't learn that yet. Imaginary numbers involve square rooting negatives and i is the square root of -1. Therefore, your answers for the other two roots are -4i and +4i.

Comment: I know i = squareroot(-1). I just mentioned I haven't seen it as a coefficient in a polynomial.

Comment: also, i should let the roots variable be something other than a or b right so it won't be confused for the coefficients of the quadratic?

Comment: yes sorry I should have used other variables for the roots, however at least now you get the idea for questions like this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your attemped solution assumes that both $2-5i$ and $2+5i$ are solutions, but we were just told that $2-5i$ is a solution.

You can simply divide $z^3-(2-5 i) z^2+16 z-32+80i$ by $z-2+5i$ (using long division). You will get that$$z^3-(2-5 i) z^2+16 z-32+80i=\bigl(z-(2-5i)\bigr)(z^2+16).$$Therefore, the other roots are $\pm4i$.

Comment: hmm, wouldn't long division take too long in an exam situation?

Comment: @Chris: Practice makes, if not perfect, then at least faster. In this case, the division works out quite nicely; try it!

Comment: @Chris "wouldn't long division take too long in an exam situation?" : No, it would not.  You know the dividend and you know the divisor.  Also, since you are given that the divisor is a root of the equation dividend = 0, you know that the quotient will have no remainder.  The division should take about 2-3 minutes, on a piece of scratch paper.  There should be no delay; your mind should go right to performing the division.  Total time spent on the problem should be about 4 minutes.

Comment: @Chris There will in fact typically be a delay.  However, the delay will be caused by your attempting to memorize the concepts, rather than learning the concepts.  As a case in point, your posting showed the fundamental error of wrongly inferring that the quotient should have all real numbers as its coefficients.  This was caused by your attempting to study Math by memorizing concepts rather than learning them.